# Should I use an NSSet or Hash Table for data that changes often

Tags: hash, nsarray, hashtable, nsset

Ignoring the time it takes to compute the actual hash function itself, the lookup of a value in the `hash` table is `O(1)`, correct?

However, anytime we change the size of the `hash` table... we would have to recreate the entire hash table. Correct? What is the computational cost of this?

Let's say we want to store somewhere between `1-500` items. Do you just create a `hash` table of `500` size to begin with? Or is that bad idea incase our data were to increase at some point to `501` items, and then we would have to recompute the entire hash table? Or do you just pick some large hash table size from the beginning that you believe you will never reach. Like `1000` items. Then this will avoid ever having to recomputer the entire hash table, help avoid collisions, etc?

Comment: *hash table is O(1), correct?*, only on average and depending on implementation

Comment: most implementations of hashing builtin in languages use a dynamic hash, only in `c` or variants, may one find hard-coded implementations of (fixed-size) hashing for specific purposes and with specific conditions